# Using Angularjs multiselect isteven

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Trying to incorporate [Angularjs multiselect](http://isteven.github.io/angular-multi-select/#/demo-grouping) into my project, however, whenever I try to pull the data from my mysql database, only the last record is being displayed.

---

**html**

```
<div isteven-multi-select
     input-model="allPersonnelGrouped"
     output-model="groupedOutput"
     button-label="icon name"
     item-label="icon name maker"
     tick-property="ticked"
     max-height="250px" 
     group-property="msGroup">
</div>
```

**angularjs**

```
$http.get('/messages/shifts').success(function(data) {

    $scope.groupedShifts = data;


    angular.forEach( $scope.groupedShifts, function( groupShift ) {

        $scope.allPersonnelGrouped = [
           { name: '<strong>All Shifts</strong>', msGroup: true },
           { name: '<strong>' + groupShift.title + '</strong>', msGroup: true },
           { icon: '', name: groupShift.personnel, maker: '(' + groupShift.email + ')', ticked: false },
           { msGroup: false },
           { msGroup: false }
        ];

    });

});
```

**array of objects**

```
[
   {
      "id": 1,
      "title": "Shift 1",
      "email": "email@gmail.com",
      "personnel": "Johnny Depp"
   },
   {
      "id": 2,
      "title": "Shift 2",
      "email": "email2@gmail.com"
      "personnel": "Napoleon Bonaparte"
   }

]
```

---

In the example the last object in the array of objects above, only the last object is shown and I need all of them to be displayed.

Essentially the output I am getting is

[image]

Comment: Only the last object is show because inside the `forEach` loop you are creating a new array each time it executes. I was typing this as an answer (and w/a solution), but in doing so I realized I wasn't sure what your resulting array should look like. Should it be an array of objects (as you've shown above), or perhaps an array of arrays, where the inner array contains objects?

Comment: @Sunil D. It should be array of objects.

Comment: what would you suggest I do in order to access each property and display all the needed data? @Sunil D.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing a `forEach` loop where you set the value of an array each time, wiping out the prior value. Instead, you want to:

1. Initialize the array `$scope.allPersonnelGrouped` with the initial menu items ("All Shifts", etc.)
2. Loop over the `$scope.groupedShifts` array and add items to `$scope.allPersonnelGrouped` to fill in the members of shift group
3. After the loop, close the menu groups

I've only spent a few minutes looking at the `multiselect` directive, so this may not be exactly what you want.

```
// initialize the array
$scope.allPersonnelGrouped = [
  { name: '<strong>All Shifts</strong>', msGroup: true } 
];

angular.forEach( $scope.groupedShifts, function( groupShift ) {
  // populate the dynamic portion of the array
  $scope.allPersonnelGrouped.push(
    { name: '<strong>' + groupShift.title + '</strong>', msGroup: true }
  );

  $scope.allPersonnelGrouped.push(
    { icon: '', name: groupShift.personnel, maker: '(' + groupShift.email + ')', ticked: false }
  );
  $scope.allPersonnelGrouped.push({ msGroup: false });
});

// close the menu groups
$scope.allPersonnelGrouped.push(
  { msGroup: false }
);
```

Comment: I was trying something similar, and your answer is almost exactly what I was looking for. its just that **groupShift.title** would be within the foreach loop (I'm assuming) or it would be undefined.  **All Shift** does nothing when trying to select it though, and if i put **groupShift.title** within the foreach loop, it does what **All Shift** is supposed to do & that is selecting all shifts within the list. @Sunil D.

Comment: Figured it out. Thanks for a great response @Sunil D.